# Content scripts on prerendered pages?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

Are Content Scripts (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) injected into prerendered pages (document.webkitVisibilityState== 'prerender') ?

I’ve been reading https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender and https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility, and am trying to figure out how Content Scripts work with page prerendering/prefetching.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TheZ, tomdemuyt: I’m afraid you guys are missing the point. ‘run_at’ specifies whether the content script is injected before or after the DOM is constructed.

However, I am talking about document.webkitVisibilityState, which can be ‘prerender’ (when the page is in a background/invisible tab), ‘hidden’, or ‘visible’. Note that webkitVisibilityState can transition from ‘prerender’ to ‘hidden’ or ‘visible’, or back and forth between ‘hidden’ and ‘visible’, without any changes being made to the DOM. (In order to better understand this, read the articles linked in my original post.)

I think I’ve been able to determine that content scripts ARE injected into prerendered pages. Here’s the problem, however: let’s say my content script does something that should not occur on a prerendered page. For instance, it does pageview count, or adds animation, neither of which should begin until the user is actually viewing the page. So it seems that my content script should do something like what’s shown in the code examples on https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility - check document.webkitVisibilityState, and also listen to the ‘webkitvisibilitychange’ event, and only do pageview count/start the animation when document.webkitVisibilityState is, or has transitioned to, ‘visible’.

I may have just answered my own question, but I just wanted to make sure that I was on the right track.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As TheZ mentioned, you should ues the run_at setting.

Link to docs : http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration